# axios.interceptors.request.use() does not execute the functions body

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm having problem with axios interceptors. I simplified my code below but it still does not execute the statement inside the "axios.interceptors.request.use()" body. Please see code below and console output for reference. Thank you.

```
import axios from 'axios'

class AuthenticationService{

    setupAxiosInterceptorsJwt(token){
    
        console.log("Setting up interceptors.")
        
        axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
                config.headers.authorization = token
                console.log("Interceptor created.");
            return config;
          }, (error) => {
                console.log("Failed");
            return Promise.reject(error);
          });
      
          console.log("Finished.");
      }

}

export default new AuthenticationService();
```

Console:

```
    Setting up interceptors.
    Finished.
```

Comment: I also tried creating an instance of the axios but still get the same output. `    
`let axiosInstance = axios.create( {baseURL:"http://localhost:4200/", headers: {"Authorization": token }} )`

Comment: @Alexander , I updated my code but it still skips the `axios.interceptors.request.use()` 's body. Is there any possible reason why it is not executed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a value (config) for the "success" handler and rejecting an error for the error handler:

```
setupAxiosInterceptorsJwt(token) {
  console.log("Setting up interceptors.")

  axios.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
      console.log("Success");
      return config;
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("Failed");
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    console.log("Finished.");
  }
```

That being said, you are specify a "request" interceptor. Technically the handler where you do `console.log("Success");` is inaccurate as the request has not yet occurred. Did you intend to instead do a "response" interceptor?

```
setupAxiosInterceptorsJwt(token) {
  console.log("Setting up interceptors.")

  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      console.log("Success");
      return response;
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("Failed");
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    console.log("Finished.");
  }
```

Either way, you need to either return the `config` or return the `response` and reject an error in the error handler.

Finally, the `console.log("Finished.");` will probably always log before the other `console.log` statements due the async nature of the requests.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send an actual request to check out that function is executed. That function is executed only when just before actual request is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a token like this

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
       config.headers = {
           Authorization: "Bearer " + token
       };
       config.withCredentials = true
     return config;
  }
)
```